# how can I get all product of a category in a custom page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-view

I have created a custom sub category page, in which I'm calling all the sub-categories, now i want to show product of each sub-categories in the same page how can I do that.

This is what I do to get my sub-categories

1 - Create a custom block **"sub-category-listing"**

2 - Then I have created a **subcategorylist.phtml** page

```
<div class="category-products sub-cat">
<ul class="products-grid" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;">
<?php
$_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories();
if($_categories->count()):
$categorycount = 0;
foreach ($_categories as $_category):
if($_category->getIsActive()):
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category- 
>getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
$catName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();

?>

<li class="item <?=$class?>">
<h2><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo 
$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this- 
>htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a></h2>
</li>
<?php
endif;
if($categorycount == 100000){
$categorycount = 0;
echo "</ul>\n\n<ul class=\"products-grid\">";
}
else{
$categorycount++;
}
endforeach;
endif;
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: does this work for you?

Comment: no it doesn't but thanks anyway

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: no, its not showing anything

Comment: did you get the list of categories >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code as per below to show all your sub category products.

```
<div class="category-products sub-cat">
    <ul class="products-grid" style="margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;">
        <?php
        $_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories();
        if($_categories->count()):
            $categorycount = 0;
        foreach ($_categories as $_category):
            if($_category->getIsActive()):
                $cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category- 
                    >getId());
            $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
            $catName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();

            ?>

            <li class="item <?=$class?>">
                <h2><a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo 
                $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this- 
                >htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a></h2>
            </li>
            <?php
            endif;
            if($categorycount == 100000){
                $categorycount = 0;
                echo "</ul>\n\n<ul class=\"products-grid\">";
            }
            else{

                /* For Fetching product by category id */
                $categoryid = $_category->getId();

                $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
                $category->load($categoryid);
                $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
                $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

                foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>
                <li class="product-item">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" />
                    </a> 
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>
                </li>
                <?php } 
                $categorycount++;
            }
            endforeach;
            endif;
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```